# how can i add spinner to the datatable buttons

Tags: html, css, datatable

I'm using datatables and I export them in csv and excel format.
But while downloading the .csv file and .execl file I need to show a spinner inside the export button which is in the datatable.

Is this possible? If possible how to do it.

Comment: you can add the css to create a spinner with animation. then use javascript to apply the css to the button and once the files have been exported remove the css. I strongly recommend providing some code and what you have tried, otherwise you'll get a limited response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found answer for this.....

```
 'buttons': [
            {
                extend: "excelHtml5",
                title: '',
                text: "Execl <span class=\"loading_spinner_ex initial_hide\"><i class=\"fa fa-spinner fa-spin\"></i></span>",
                    className: "btn btn-md btn-success btn-track1",
            }
        ]
```

and after that,

```
 $( ".btn-track" )
        .mouseup(function() {
            $(".loading_spinner_ex").hide();
        })
        .mousedown(function() {
            $(".loading_spinner_ex").show();
        });
```